# Occasional use refrigerator problems?

Tags: refrigerator

If I want to use a mini fridge for camping trips, but not between trips at home, and leave it unplugged until the day before the trip to cool it down. Will there be any detrimental effects to the life of the fridge?

Answer (score 1):

It will be absolutely fine, so long as you store it clean and dry. We have had a few over the years, of various types, and they've all been fine.

Comment: I agree just keep the door open so it doesn't mold.